# Sklearn Combine Multiple Feature Sets in Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two set of data that I want to transform using the count vectorizer. The first is for *product_title* and the second is for *product_description*. I am attempting to auto-classify the products into around 5 different categories and around 50 different sub-categories. I expect the text in the *product_title* to be more relevant so I would want the ability to weight it differently then the text in the *product_descriptions*. I am trying to create a script to combine them. So far this is what I have:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pprint import pprint
from time import time
import logging

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

print(__doc__)

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

data = {'data':[],'target1':[],'target2':[]}
tempdata = {'data1':[],'data2':[]}
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        data['data'].append(row[0])
        tempdata['data1'].append(row[-2])
        tempdata['data2'].append(row[-1])

###############################################################################
# define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with a simple
# classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])

# uncommenting more parameters will give better exploring power but will
# increase processing time in a combinatorial way
parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    #'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    #'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    #'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    #'clf__n_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # multiprocessing requires the fork to happen in a __main__ protected
    # block

    # find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
    # classifier
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)

    print("Performing grid search...")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(parameters)
    t0 = time()
    grid_search.fit(data.data, data.target)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()

    print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

The problem I am having is with:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])
```

I would need to somehow run something like:

```
combined_features = FeatureUnion([('title', data['data1']), ('description', data['data2']))
```

And I would need to run combined_features so that a CountVectorizer is applied to each *data['data1']* and *data['data2']* and then the features are combined and run through the pipeline. I would prefer to do this so that I can just feed to feature sets and the targets to the pipeline and it would do the rest. The result would allow duplicates. For example theoretically there could be features like *computer_title* and *computer_description*. Any advice on how to integrate this would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Feature Union with Heterogeneous Data Sources](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) example from the scikit-learn docs also has a simple `ItemSelector` `Transformer` that basically picks one feature from a dict (or other structure) to work with, which could be combined with a [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#featureunion-composite-feature-spaces).

```
class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """For data grouped by feature, select subset of data at a provided key.

    The data is expected to be stored in a 2D data structure, where the first
    index is over features and the second is over samples.  i.e.

    >> len(data[key]) == n_samples

    Please note that this is the opposite convention to sklearn feature
    matrixes (where the first index corresponds to sample).

    ItemSelector only requires that the collection implement getitem
    (data[key]).  Examples include: a dict of lists, 2D numpy array, Pandas
    DataFrame, numpy record array, etc.

    >> data = {'a': [1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 8],
               'b': [9, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3]}
    >> ds = ItemSelector(key='a')
    >> data['a'] == ds.transform(data)

    ItemSelector is not designed to handle data grouped by sample.  (e.g. a
    list of dicts).  If your data is structured this way, consider a
    transformer along the lines of `sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    key : hashable, required
        The key corresponding to the desired value in a mappable.
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]
```

Comment: Why do we need to have this class? Why is only FeatureUnion not enough to append features?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Pandas, [sklearn-pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn-pandas/) looks like it does what you want.

But it would be nice to have a simple built-in method for what seems like a fairly common need.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to run your pipeline once for each featuresets and then combine the results in some sort of a classifier ensemble if you want to assign different weights to them. There is [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) you may want to use.